# Retriving values trough a multi level query with eloquent relations in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve the latest records from a [MEASUREMENTS]table that is linked to a [SENSORS] table which is linked to a [RECORDERS] table.

Something like: give the last measurement of all the sensors of a specific recorder

I already defined the relations in the different models and succeeded in retrieving a multilevel collection (array) with **all** the values.
But is there a way to only get the last measured values using Eloquent in Larvel 8

**Recorder Model**

```
public function getSensorsRelation() {
return $this->hasMany(Sensor::class, 'recorder_id', 'id');}
```

**Sensor Model**

```
public function getMeasurementsRelation() {
return $this->hasmany('App\Models\measurement', 'sensor_id', 'id');}
```

**Controller query**

```
$recorderDataset = Recorder::where('id', $timeslot->recorder_id)
                   ->with('getSensorsRelation.getMeasurementsRelation')
                   ->get();
```

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkitz.png)

[dd() after update answer from @Haridarshan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrFCI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the last measurement, try something like this in reverse order

```
Measurement::whereHas('getSensorsRelation', function ($query) use ($timeslot) {
    return $query->where('recorder_id', $timeslot->recorder_id)
})->orderByDesc('id')->first();
```

Edit -
Add one more relation in your Sensor Model

```
public function getLatestMeasurement() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\measurement', 'sensor_id', 'id')->latest('id');
}
```

And then just query this new relation instead of `getMeasurementsRelation`

```
Recorder::where('id', $timeslot->recorder_id)
->with('getSensorsRelation.getLatestMeasurement')
->get();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it worked partially. your query resulted in the last value of the last sensor of the recorder. My aim was to get a response with the last value of all the sensors belonging to a specific recorder. 

Recorder -> sensor 1 -> last value
              -> sensor 2 -> last value
              -> sensor 3 -> last value   
              -> sensor 4 -> last value
              -> sensor 5 -> last value

and not only return -> sensor 5 -> last value
Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated the answer, can you try the updated one

Comment: I'm receiving a collection of the correct recorder with the correct collection of sensors. But the `getMeasurementsRelation` array is now empty. I Have attached a dd(); at the bottom of the main post

Comment: @vennot_be Updated the answer, hope it works this time